# Why would Bran Stark use ravens to spy on the Night King?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the most recent episode of *Game of Thrones* (season 7, episode 5), Bran Stark uses ravens to spy on the Night King. My question is...  why? I was under the impression greenseers such as Bran could see the everything in the present.

Comment: I interprete it the way that the library he downloaded into his brain doesn't have a good search functionality. *In theory*, he can see everything, in practice he's not yet at the point where he can willingly choose what to see. Warging into some ravens is much easier for now.

Comment: @Annatar This makes a lot of sense to me. It seems that Bran might need a trigger so that he "remembers" stuff (are you remembering current events such as spying?). For example being in the Godswood with Sansa reminds him of her wedding night.

Comment: @Annatar Guess some maesters need to start writing the google spell.

Comment: As far as I remember Greenseers don't always see everything as they were everywhere simultaneously, but rather they **can** literally see the world though different eyes. There are a lot of ravens. AND, while watching the episode I felt like it is some kind of precausion. Yes, he is ONE of the ravens, but please, dear Knight King, find out which of the big flock it is. We already know the Knight King can get to Bran when he is warging, so being a sitting duck (literally) may be unwise.

Answer (score 20):

In the books, it's clear that Bran can't see everything but can only see events occurring within sight of a weirwood tree. His use of ravens may be warging, unrelated to his greenseer power, since several Starks seem to have some ability in that direction.

Comment: I do recall GRRM saying all Stark children show the gift of warging. +1.

Comment: ["I don't know if I want to get into genetics - this is fantasy, not scifi" He replied. "I don't think this is necessarily a 'Stark' ability, though all the children have it to one extent or another. They also realize it to one extent or another. Arya doesn't realize she has it, she keeps thinking she has these weird dreams, and of course Bran is much further along".](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/1260)

Comment: And he was warging into a raven that is correct

Comment: Bran can see events that are nowhere near a weirwood tree. **He saw how Lyanna Stark died inside the Tower of Joy.** I don't think there was a tree growing inside her bedroom. From that scene, I assumed he can see anywhere and anywhen.

Comment: @RichS I agree that is problematic, and has not yet been explained either in the books or the TV show. Perhaps he can also tap the collective memory of the Starks.

Comment: Bran also knew of Arya's list of enemies even though she recited it when she was not near a weirwood tree. To my best knowledge since weirwoods are rare in the south and becoming less common in the north than they were centuries ago.

Comment: @Aegon you have an answer saying all Stark children show the gift of warging!

Comment: @Edlothiad [Yes and?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/134650/54887)

Comment: @Aegon just because you made it seem like "I'd heard a thing once which said"

Comment: @Edlothiad I hear a lot of things and I answer a number of questions :) Don't remember most of them. Should be evident, given the links used as sources in the answer, and in the comment are different (Although the one used in my answer is better, come to think of it). Took me some time to look it up when you mentioned it. I should probably start asking you instead whenever I am looking for a comment I made, a question I answered or a review I made within the span of the last year.

Comment: @RichS maybe there was a Raven watching Lyanna from the window sill?

Comment: Remember when Bran used the tree to see the army of the dead and then the king grabbed his arm? If he uses ravens instead (by whatever mechanism) he is safe from that kind of thing.

Comment: some other possible explanations: maybe he can not control what he sees. Maybe even if he sees the Night Kings's army he can't tell where on the map they are, or even if what he sees is in the present or in the past.

Comment: @RichS As an ad-hoc theory; Maybe the bed (or wall or cabinet or whatever) in the room was made from wood from a weirwood tree.

Answer (score 6):

I originally thought that Bran sees through the Weirwood Trees, but he *is* the three-eyed raven, so I guess he can see through their eyes too. *But* some of the guys in this thread are correct - it seems that Bran can see things that are not in line-of-sight of either Tree or Animal.

So now I'm thinking Bran can tap into the "sight" (senses I guess) of any living thing; perhaps Bran can see through the eyes of men too - after all he can Warg into Hodor, which is something 'no-one' can do according to Jojen Reed.

Seeing as how the White Walkers are not men and their army are dead, Bran would have to send a living organism into what is essentially a lifeless desert.

Comment: `warg into hodor`....The term is Skin Changing. Warging is when a Skin Changer takes control of a member of the Canine species i.e. Dogs or Wolves.  Since Hodor is neither dog nor Wolf, it isn't warging .All Wargs are skin changers but not all skin changers are Wargs.

Comment: @Aegon: This appears to be a [difference between the books and the TV show](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Warg#In_the_books).

Comment: Jojen is wrong. Varamyr was able to skin-change into 'Thistle'. This was unsuccessful because of her extreme mental and physical resistance - to the point of self-mutilation - but there didn't seem to be a fundamental reason why 'the Gift' wouldn't work on humans. Perhaps a child would be easier to control.

Comment: @TheMathemagician Was it no one _can_ do it, or no one _should_ do it? Bran skin-changing into Hodor was clearly a big no-no.

Comment: @Llewellyn Indeed. Varamyr recalls his training days when his mentor told him that skin changing into a human is "abomination". It can be done but it shouldn't be done.

Comment: I didn't actually remember Varamyr from the books, I guess it's time for a re-read. But while this is all fascinating, are we looking for an answer to the question about the TV show, or the books? Original question was about the TV show.

Comment: @Mark Nah you are doing fine. The Question is tagged with show tag and answer should be based on show-canon.

Comment: Thanks Aegon, I was getting a bit confused. It's been a couple of years since I read ASOIAF but I'm on S05E06 of my back to back rewatch, so I'm a bit more current on TV canon.