# Did Carl Sagan ever explain how God modified the value of π?

Tags: contact, carl-sagan

Near the end of the book, *Contact*, by Carl Sagan, the main character is told there are messages hidden deep in the base-11 digits of π.

From [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_(novel)):

> Acting on the suggestion of "Ted", Ellie works on a program to compute the digits of π to heretofore-unprecedented lengths. When Ellie looks at what the computer has found, she sees a circle rasterized from 0's and 1's that appear after 10^20 places in the base 11 representation of π. This not only provides evidence of her journey, but suggests that intelligence is behind the universe itself.

Somebody as smart as Carl Sagan should know that the creator(s) of the universe can no more change the value of π than they can change any other fact. Math itself must precede both the universe and anything or anyone that created it.

I could better believe a deity chose to hide a message inside the [Fine-Structure Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant) than in π.

**Did Carl Sagan ever provide an explanation for how a deity would embed hidden messages deep inside the value of π?**

I am looking for answers from the novel or from Carl Sagan's writings or interviews. I don't want answers from the movie, [Contact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_(1997_American_film)), since that does not mention any messages hidden in the value of π.

Comment: Can you please clarify why you think God *modified* pi rather than just starting the universe with that particular value of pi? Or is that what you mean by *"Math itself must precede both the universe and anything or anyone that created it."*?

Comment: @Wikis God cannot change math. The concepts of zero and one, pi, e, addition, subtraction, and multiplication are essential to laws of physics. You cannot describe physics without using math. The values of zero and one are not based on any laws of physics for this universe or any universe that could ever exist. Instead, the equations describing laws of physics are based on math. Therefore, math must precede the universe since it is more fundamental than physics.

Comment: @RichS - In philosophical terms, an omnipotent deity can change *anything*, even fundamental concepts. Or else it isn't omnipotent

Comment: @Valorum I don't think God is all powerful given the Omnipotence Paradox. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnipotence_paradox

Comment: I've voted to close. It looks like you're seeking a *scientific explanation* for how a deity would muck with fundamental concepts (e.g. whether it's actually possible).

Comment: @Valorum I am not asking for a scientific explanation. I am asking if the author provided an explanation for a logically impossible plot event. I don't see this as much different than asking how a different authors may explain faster-than-light travel in their stories, which is believed to be physically impossible.

Comment: I'm not sure why I'd need an author statement to explain a material fact. Any more than I need one to say the sky is blue.

Comment: @Jontia The question is stated in bold in the original post. **Did Carl Sagan ever provide an explanation** for how a deity would embed hidden messages deep inside the value of π? The answer should be to that question, not whether you have some other encoding idea in mind.

Comment: An answer can challenge the premise of the question and answer without having to address Carl Sagan’s explanation if a factual explanation exists, as @Jontia has presented. If there is a fundamental misunderstanding in the question an answer can challenge it as such as long as it attempts to answer the question asked, which they have done

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79987/discussion-on-question-by-richs-did-carl-sagan-ever-explain-how-god-modified-the).

Comment: You're still trying to treat *Contact* as if it were hard science fiction.

Comment: ... I think my previous comment is apropro here: "Complaining that it is impossible for Pi to contain a message is no more sensible IMO than complaining that it is impossible for Aslan to have been resurrected, or for the Kings and Queens to have become children again when they left Narnia; or, if you prefer, complaining that it is impossible for Lorien to have resurrected Sheridan."  It's a neat idea.  It doesn't have to make sense.

Comment: This is pretty opinion-based. If a creator of all that is exists, it/they CREATED maths. Your whole question is based on a nonsensical premise. If you edit it to be just the bold text it might fly.

Comment: @Conrad, just so.  People keep talking about "changing" π but in the context of the story the message in π was embedded into the structure of mathematics when mathematics was created.  (If you'll excuse the grammatical imprecision.)  Now, *my* objection to that is that it seems very unlikely that there would be enough degrees of freedom, but on the other hand "degrees of freedom" is a mathematical concept so there's an obvious problem there too. :-)

Answer (score 6):

**Unlikely.**

The whole *point* of the story was that the message in π was inexplicable.  In other words, that it was a genuine miracle, real and irrefutable evidence for the existence of God.

> Your story has been foretold.  It's happened before.  Somewhere inside of you, you must have known.  None of your details are in the Book of Genesis.  Of course not.  How could they be?  The Genesis account was right for the time of Jacob.  Just as your witness is right for this time, for our time.

(Chapter 23, *Reprogramming*.)

**Any attempt at explaining the inexplicable, describing the mechanism behind a miracle in human terms, would have fatally undermined the story.**  Granted, authors do occasionally undermine their own stories, but I consider it unlikely in this particular case.

---

To expand on that a little, I suspect that this quote from your question summarizes the reason that you feel there ought to be an explanation of some sort:

> Math itself must precede both the universe and anything or anyone that created it.

... but that isn't a falsifiable statement; there is no meaningful way to argue either in favour or against this proposition.  There is therefore no particular reason to believe that Dr. Sagan considered your proposition to be so obviously and objectively true that it did not make sense to even speculate about a universe in which it is not.

It is of course your prerogative to consider him wrong in that respect.  But even if that is so, even very smart people can be wrong sometimes.  It is more likely in my opinion that he simply didn't consider it to be a problem than that he believed it to be a problem but had come up with some complicated excuse to put it in the story anyway.

I leave you with [The Parable of Hemlock](https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/bcM5ft8jvsffsZZ4Y/the-parable-of-hemlock):

> Logic never dictates any empirical question; it never settles any real-world query which could, by any stretch of the imagination, go either way.

Comment: All that said, I will of course delete this answer if someone finds a quote that contradicts me.

Comment: This is as silly as saying 1+1=3. If Sagan put "1+1=3" into his story, would you defend that as a miracle?

Comment: @LincolnMan, the only inherent problem with a 1+1=3 story is that a universe in which that were true would be incomprehensible to us, making it unlikely that you could tell a compelling story with that premise.  A universe in which π contains a message is unlikely, but it doesn't interfere with the storytelling.

Comment: You say "1+1=3" means the universe would be incomprehensible, but believe a message can be hidden in pi? You can't change pi any more than you can make 1+1=3. They are both wrong.

Comment: @LincolnMan, but you're perfectly happy with [direwolves](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175474/when-did-the-stark-children-first-show-warging-skills)?  I find that baffling.

Comment: @LincolnMan, we know that 1+1 does not equal 3. so this can't be our universe. we do not know (yet) if there's a message hidden in pi.

Comment: @ths, that's a good way of looking at it.  We're talking about a fantasy element (even though the novel taken as a whole is science fiction) so it isn't a question of "believing" that it is possible.  A 1+1=3 universe would be different from ours in so many very bizarre ways that I doubt a story could be effective (though if someone wants to try, more power to them!) but Dr. Sagan's π-has-a-message universe is different from ours in such a very subtle way that we can't even be absolutely certain that it *is* a difference.

Answer (score 2):

My original comment said;

> The digits of pi are infinite and the message is only "part" of the value. Given that as a starting point and complete freedom to describe the method of encoding any message you like can be hidden within the value of pi.

Now bear in mind we've only calculated the 2,000,000,000,000,000th position of pi. That's 2*10^15 in base 10. That's 1 million times smaller than the starting point for Sagan's message. And most online pi searches cap out a lot lower.

If we use a simple A1Z26 encoding, that is replace the letter A with 1, B with 2 and so on with Z as 26. I can find the RichS written in Pi at 10,319,866.

[Encoder](https://www.dcode.fr/letter-number-cipher) RichS = 1893819 
[Searcher](https://www.angio.net/pi/bigpi.cgi) Your name is at; Position 10,319,866 counting from the first digit after the decimal point. The 3. is not counted.

Given more flexibility, the choice of base, more digits to work from and different ciphers, quite literally every message is in there somewhere.

Comment: @user14111 I saw that in the comments above. I guess my response is why would he need to? To quote Vernor Vinge from the great Marooned in Realtime. "You can find any message you want in there if the coding scheme is nutty enough".

Comment: This answer is not even wrong. It missed the point of the question.

Comment: @Jontia If some author wrote about faster-than-light travel and you posted a question about how FTL travel works in that author's books, how would you reply to an answer that describes a different method of FTL but does not mention the author at all?

Comment: @RichS But FTL is not an established fact. The details about irrational numbers that I've supplied are facts. If someone asked a question about internal combustion engines I'd feel happy providing the answer from other information sources. I will grant you, the exact message Sagan wrote about and it's exact position and encoding is almost certainly not present in the actual digits of Pi.

Comment: @DonFusili The difference is that FTL is (to our best knowledge) considered physically impossible  (and changing the digits of pi is mathematically impossible), but internal combustion engines are possible. Anybody mentioning internal combustion engines as a counterexample is the one making a strawman argument. The real question for Jontia is what this answer has to do with Carl Sagan.

Comment: @user14111 I'm not aware of any statement by Sagan about this critique specifically. If someone does find one and wants to put it as an answer then I'll happily up vote it. I find it unlikely that such a statement exists, simply because the idea of a message inside an infinite irrational number is a mathematical joke. I would therefore assume as with any joke explaining it would defeat the purpose.

Comment: @user14111 there's not even any evidence that anyone has made this critique before, so why would the author respond to it? Further, the critique is based on a false premise / misunderstanding. It's like asking "what did Sagan have to say about spelling Contact with a C?" - well, nothing, because that's how it's spelled.

Comment: @user14111 eight years after he died. And the second point of my argument is the stronger one.

Comment: @user14111 it cannot be a well-known blunder when it's not actually a blunder. While that message probably isn't there at that position, nobody's actually been able to check yet.

Comment: The point made by this answer is addressed and refuted within the story itself. The important thjng is not that the message exists (as is pointed out, all finite messages exist somewhere in pi), but that it occurs inexplicably early, whereas the expected position of such a message is many orders of magnitude further into the sequence.

Comment: (Now, I personally am not comfortable with this argument which seems non conclusive to me, but then again reflecting on the theme of the book I suspect I'm not supposed to be comfortable with it. But the point remains that Sagan seems to be suggesting that it was possible that the message was intentionally placed there, therefore the question is valid: how did he believe this would have been achieved?)

Comment: @Jontia Nice try at providing an encoding idea, but this is really not an answer. This "answer" is just an elaboration on what you were trying to say in a comment to the question, and does not truly answer the question. A real answer (whether wrong or right) would provide quotes from Carl Sagan. I flagged your answer for moderation attention.